# How to get a tuple based on list of template templates of variable size in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, tuples, variadic-templates, generic-programming

I have created a template class which takes two plain template parameters (like int or double) and have derived several other classes from it:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class IClassBase {...}

template <typename B>
class Derived1Class : public IClassBase<std::string, B> {...}

template <typename B>
class Derived2Class : public IClassBase<std::string, B> {...}
```

I need to design a structure which would allow compiler to build a std::tuple based on list of template types and their parameters (B type in code snippet above).

So given the list below

```
Derived1Class<int>, Derived1Class<double>, Derived2Class<bool>, Derived2Class<std::string>
```

compiler should infer following tuple:

```
std::tuple<int, double, bool, std::string>
```

Is this even possible, and if so, how it can be done in C++?

Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this even possible, and if so, how it can be done in C++?

Anything is possible in C++. Especially the current C++ standard. Tested with gcc 6.2.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template<typename template_type> class extract_param;

template<template<typename T> typename template_param, typename template_param_t>
class extract_param<template_param<template_param_t>> {

public:
    typedef template_param_t type_t;
};

template<typename ...Args>
using extract_tuple=std::tuple<typename extract_param<Args>::type_t...>;


template<typename T> class sometemplate {};

int main()
{
    extract_tuple< sometemplate<int>, sometemplate<std::string>> tuple;

    int &intref=std::get<0>(tuple);
    std::string &stringref=std::get<1>(tuple);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, even though this may work, the code is pretty unreadable and hard to understand, I think this should be avoided :D

Comment: If you think that's unreadable, pick any header, `<vector>`, `<algorithm>`, and try to read it yourself. Nobody has ever accused C++ of being crystal clear. As the `C++` tag on stackoverflow.com is the witness to...

Comment: Yeah, probably I'm just not used with how messy the C++ syntax can get :D

Comment: Mark my words. After 20 years of hacking C++, the above code should read like poetry, to you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for your response, it really helped. However there is yet another use case I wanted to cover.
`template <typename T, template <T, typename> typename ... Args>
class A{extract_tuple<Args> tuple;}`
Could you please comment on whether this is achievable with your approach?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking there, sorry.